# Draw on imageview image in android?

Tags: android, image

Fellow Programmers,

I am new to android and I am trying to draw on a image based on giving the x and y axis of the image as the input.So that he pixel value corresponding to the coordinate gets filled with a color that I mention. Say Red color for now.

User Story: Render a image through image view and on a button click I need to pass the co-ordinate value for the image that represents the pixel of the image and fill it with red color. Keep on doing it looks like drawing on the image that I render using image view.

Is this user story is possible to do in Android? If then help me on this. I referred the draw class and canvas class and not sure how to implement.

Looking forward to ur help on developing this user story on android application.

Best,

Googler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take a blank canvas.
2. Draw your image on the canvas.
3. Draw points on the canvas by specifying x and y co-ordinates and red color in paint.

Comment: Thanks @user603125..
Can you share some examples or links related to the canvas u mentioned?